# Continuous UDP communication resulting in GC Sweep and stops receiving

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, android-asynctask, udp, threadpool

I am trying to communicate with an embedded UDP server from my android device and on receipt of a UDP packet, I am updating my UI. The communication works fine for ~250 iterations (query - response) and then pops a GC Sweep Major and the UDP socket stops receiving. I am new to android development and I am not sure whether the implementation of my UDP communication is done correctly

This is what I have ...

```
    void Initialize_UDP()
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => UDPCommunicator());
        update_flag = true;
    }

    void UDPCommunicator()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (update_flag)
            {
                try
                {
                    byte[] buffer = FrameGenerator(1, 0, true);
                    byte[] data = new byte[25];
                    CheckQuery(buffer);
                    var sender = default(IPEndPoint);
                    using (UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(15001))
                    {
                        udpClient.EnableBroadcast = true;
                        udpClient.Send(buffer, buffer.Length, "192.168.4.255", 15000);
                        udpClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 500;
                        data = udpClient.Receive(ref sender);
                        socket_active = false;
                    }
                    CheckResponse(data);
                    /*RunOnUiThread(() =>
                    {
                        Update_UI(data);
                    }); */
                }
                catch (SocketException)
                {
                    Log.Debug("Error", "Socket Error: Timeout");
                }
            }                
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
```

This is the error I receive

09-25 14:20:01.795 D/A       ( 7595): Response: 35 68 1 18 56 231 2 0 223 137 23 8 0 0 0 0 2 1 14 19 0 1 185

09-25 14:20:01.896 D/A       ( 7595): Query: 35 81 1 0 139

09-25 14:20:01.941 I/zygote  ( 7595): Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 4890(372KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 50% free, 1628KB/3MB, paused 170us total 35.511ms

09-25 14:20:01.941 D/Mono    ( 7595): GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 21 objects 24 opaque 1 colors 21 colors-bridged 21 colors-visible 21 xref 0 cache-hit 0 cache-semihit 0 cache-miss 0 setup 0.07ms tarjan 0.06ms scc-setup 0.06ms gather-xref 0.00ms xref-setup 0.00ms cleanup 0.05ms

09-25 14:20:01.942 D/Mono    ( 7595): GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 37.27ms

09-25 14:20:01.942 D/Mono    ( 7595): GC_MINOR: (Concurrent start) time 5.32ms, stw 8.02ms promoted 114K major size: 848K in use: 170K los size: 17408K in use: 16067K

09-25 14:20:01.942 D/Mono    ( 7595): GC_MAJOR_CONCURRENT_START: (LOS overflow)

09-25 14:20:02.442 D/Error   ( 7595): Socket Error: Timeout
09-25 14:20:02.544 D/A       ( 7595): Query: 35 81 1 0 139

Comment: You're setting the Timeout on the UdpClient to 500 milliseconds. The GC freezes all code while collecting, and it seems like either the GC is taking more than 500 ms to clean or with the added GC delay the message roundtrip is taking longer than 500 ms. Just up your Timeout to something more reasonable like a few seconds

Comment: Also, how are you handling packet loss?

Comment: you could just have a pool of udpclients, rather than make and destroy every packet

Comment: @MindSwipe Regarding packet loss, a loss of a few packets doesn't have much of an impact as the rate of variation in the data received from the server is very low. Also no calculations are being done on the App side besides updating a few UI elements (which I have currently commented out to find out the cause)

Comment: @BugFinder You mean separate UDP clients for Send and Receive along thread safe Queues?

Comment: @BilalKazi not necessarily from the code youve shown you make a new updclient each time, dont, reuse.. then there is less gc

Comment: I agree with BugFinder, creating a new UdpClient every loop puts unnecessary load on the GC. I recommend you create the UdpClient once and reuse it

Comment: @BugFinder Thanks, problem solved. However, I had imagined enclosing an object in using statement disposes it and doesn't require garbage collection or maybe helps in garbage collection...

Comment: nope each time you made one and eventually there was enough memory mess to cause gc.  by having a pool you can handle multiples but keep memory usage the same

Comment: @BugFinder Any link or post you could direct me to where I can learn more about using UDP Pool?

Comment: Not specifically but there is plenty on pooling as a whole, tcp pooling would be very similar

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of too short a timeout. The `UdpClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout` is time in milliseconds. The Stacktrace shows that it took exactly 500 milliseconds between "GC_MAJOR_CONCURRENT_START: (LOS overflow)" and "Socket Error: Timeout", so this is the cause. The solution to this is to increase the Timeout of the UDP Client, the default value is "0" which means infinite, and/ or add error handling to the timeout event

Comment: I increased the timeout to 5000ms but that hasn't helped. The response is usually received from the server within 200ms so I don't think the 'Receive Timeout' is the cause

Comment: Then the problem could be that the UDP Packet form the server isn't arriving. UDP doesn't guarantee reliable or even ordered delivery of packets (more [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/96160)).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by BugFinder & MindSwipe, creating a new UdpClient every loop puts unnecessary load on the GC and a better alternative is to reuse the UdpClient which has resolved the issue. Also, using a UDP pool in an async fashion further improves the performance. Below is my implementation (simplified for brevity)

```
void Initialize_UDP()
    {
        UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient();
        UdpClient r_UdpClient = new UdpClient(15001);
        IPEndPoint sender = default(IPEndPoint);
        ManualResetEventSlim receive = new ManualResetEventSlim(true);
        Task.Run(() => UDP_Transmit());
    }

async void UDP_Transmit()
        {
            byte[] frame;
            SelectFrameQueue(selector);
            udpClient = new UdpClient(15001);
            udpClient.EnableBroadcast = true;
            udpClient.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(UDP_Receive), udpClient);
            while (true)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < frame_Queue.Length; i++)
                {                    
                        frame = FrameGenerator(frame_Queue[i]);  //Generates Frames
                        try
                        {
                            udpClient.Send(frame, frame.Length, "192.168.4.255", 15000);
                        }
                        catch (SocketException)
                        {
                            Log.Debug("Error", "Socket Exception");
                        }

                        if(!receive.Wait(10000))   //Receive Timeout
                        {
                            RunOnUiThread(() =>
                            {
                                ShowToast("Connection Timeout. Please check device");
                            });
                        };
                        await Task.Delay(update_delay);    //To release pressure from H/W
                        receive.Reset();                        
                }                             
            }
        }

void UDP_Receive(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            receive.Set();
            r_UdpClient = result.AsyncState as UdpClient;
            data = r_UdpClient.EndReceive(result, ref sender);
            RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {               
                Update_UI(data);                            
            });
            r_UdpClient.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(UDP_Receive), r_UdpClient);            
        }
```